# Javascript, Cannot read property of undefined, but prints to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]I have a `jQuery` call which is getting the data in to a object.
I'm trying to use the object value to set as a label text from `javascript`, but it throws

> "Cannot read property '0' of undefined."

where as it prints the value successfully to the console.

```html
var questionData;
var optionData;

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'coaching-assessment-tool.aspx/GetCATQuestionAndOptions',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {            
            questionData = data.d[0];
            optionData = data.d[1];           
            console.log(questionData[0].QuestionText);
            console.log("Question Data", questionData);
            console.log("Option Data", optionData);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Error retrieving data. Please contact support.');
        }        
    });
    document.getElementById('firstQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[0].QuestionText;
});
```

I need the label text as the object value (questionData[0].QuestionText).[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Live console output will update when the object changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.ajax()` [is asynchronous by default](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), so setting `innerHTML` is happening before `questionData` is populated. Move line 22 inside the success callback to make sure the data is available before it is used.

While it's technically possible to make the call synchronous, it's a bad idea.

```
$.ajax({
   // ...
   async: false,
   // ...
});
```

That code would prevent *any* other JavaScript from executing until the ajax call is complete.

Just as an aside, some JavaScript tooling like [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) can help you catch those mistakes before the code executes in a browser. I've recently converted some JS to TS and been *very* happy with the number of bugs I've caught.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, it did work, I appreciate it.

Comment: You bet! If it completely fixed your issue, please mark the answer as correct. It'll help other folks find answers to similar issues.  :-)

Comment: Yeah I did mark it, I hope some day I'll work on TS, I'm more of a .net developer actually. Thanks for the help. Since you are here shall I ask you another question?

Comment: The `$.ajax({ async: false })` call is just a partial example of a synchronous call, to show what it would look like. You'd have to provide additional options for it to actually do anything useful.

Comment: I couldn't paste the code in the comment 
var ddlFirstResponse = $('#ddlFirstResponse');
            ddlFirstResponse.empty(); 
            ddlFirstResponse.append($("<option></option>").val('').html(''));
            $.each(data, function (i, optionData) {
                ddlFirstResponse.append($("<option></option>").val(optionData.OptionId).html(optionData.OptionText));
            });

Comment: I added that after the line 22 in the javascript, it doesn't throw error not output it gives

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I think I can help with that, but I don't think it's related to the `undefined` issue. Please open a new question with details about this problem, and I'll try to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193494/discussion-between-michael-crenshaw-and-ananth-asamani).